# Get property type for Ember-Data object

Tags: ember.js

Given the following:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  firstName: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Is there a way to determine the type for `firstName`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
App.User.metaForProperty('firstName').type
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript's `typeof`:

```
// Find the type of the first model's firstName.
console.log(typeof userController.objectAt(0).get('firstName'));
```

Ember.JS also has an in-built `typeOf`: `Ember.typeOf`, but in this case it doesn't offer any advantages, as far as I can see.